# Can DHCP be removed as Tag Synonym for Networking?

Tags: discussion, tags

Networking is very general and large, DHCP will narrow it much down.

As DHCP is a dynamically created range of IP which will be automatically assigned to a device.
Networking on the other hand is very large.

If a user decides to enter the Tag DHCP it will be a much easier subject to handle than just Networking.

I'll add an excerpt and other information if it can be done.

---

- [networking](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) (1121 tagged)

  > Questions about configuring, troubleshooting or using connections that one device uses to talk to another.
- [dhcp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dhcp) (synonym, 2 renames)

Comment: What would splitting the tags do that can't be accomplished by simply searching for DHCP in the first place? Basically, could you elaborate on why this would be good or what benefit accrues if the change were made?

Comment: I tought of DHCP being a bigger part, but I assume finding for networking will do as grgarside answered.  Time to accept it and move on.

Comment: It's a good question, thanks for asking it - I didn't mean to shut down discussion if here was more to the thought or you want to expand on it later. I should have answered yes, the synonym can be split and building a rationale why here is the best way to do it.

Comment: I understand it, but I tought of a person knowing a bit more of DHCP than any other "default" networking question it would be nice to split it up. But grgarside point is valid enough for me.

Comment: If you know enough about dhcp I suspect you would be looking (and definitely if you are asking) on ServerFault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I disagree with this, since every question tagged *dhcp* should be tagged *networking* anyway and if someone tags with *dhcp* but not *networking* then the question may be missed by those that are following the *networking* tag (this would mean that one would have to follow two tags) and would probably lead to the question being edited to add the *networking* tag.

Comment: I'll add: It's also very likely that any question about DHCP would have already mentioned that term specifically, so a tag adds little, whereas a question about DHCP might not have mentioned the word "networking", so that tag is additive.